# Preemptible TPU - Data Managment while persistant disks are not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have access to 1 Preemptible Cloud TPU v3-32, and I want to train my LM on it, however, since it is preemptible, I can't attach a persistent disk (read-write mode) to it as it is also mentioned in [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/setup-persistent-disk#overview).
My dataset is around 100GB.
These were the things I did but none worked:

1. **Preprocessed and Cached the data on another VM and saved them on PD then attached the PD to TPU in read-only mode**: Write Permission Error for the time my code wants to lock the lock file.
2. **Using Google Buckets and TFDA to stream the data**: The problem here is the caching, Space needed for caching is about 250GB which is not available.

I am using Jax/Flax and the script is available here. [SCRIPT](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/flax/language-modeling/run_mlm_flax.py)

Comment: What's the exact permission error that you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TPU v3-32` has 4 hosts (each has 8 TPU cores attached), each one with 340 GB DRAM and about 100 GB disk storage. So if you wanted to shared your dataset 4 ways you could save it on 4 hosts.

But I recommend storing your dataset in GCS bucket, and using distributed tf.data (or other options) to process, map, prefetch, batch in parallel on each hosts (each hosts needs to process 1/4 of the data from your dataset per epoch).

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance

https://github.com/google/seqio is another option to consider.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was also wondering if it is possible to just create ```TPU pod``` and access to the tpu pod through GCP VM?

Comment: Yes, you can, here is an example of `Pods with remote coordinator`: https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/pytorch-pods#pods_with_remote_coordinator for Pytorch/XLA (for Tensorflow and Jax it can be done similarly.

* Run those long running scripts with nohub, tmux, screen, etc 
*  A simple retry script for tracking Pod`s health status: https://github.com/allenwang28/tpu_retry

You could also use Ray cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I searched for such thing before but I couldn't find it. Thanks again for sharing <3 <3

Comment: I am still struggling training the model on v3-32. My LM is huge and I can't fit it to a single v3-8. So, knowing this I can't use TPUStrategy of TF as it replicates the model on each v3-8. Can you give me a way around to handle this issue?

Comment: How large is you LM? TPU v4-8 has 32GB HBM per host.

Comment: TPUStrategy only offers data parallelism.  [TF DTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/dtensor_overview) which is very experimental, it offers model parallelism.
If you are open to considering other frameworks: JAX/Flax have paxml, t5x, maxtext LLM models from google with model/data parallelism, on more from huggingface.
Pytorch/XLA also support data/model sharding (though FSDP).

Comment: I am training Roberta-Large (123M parameters). I have free access to only V3-32 TPU pods. And I can't find any useful scripts for helping me train the model :/.
I would appreciate if you give me some refs. OR another connection method to get advices from you.

Comment: 123M params model easily fits on TPU v-32 replicated. Not sure why you are seeing OOM. For references you can follow Tensorflow 2 model garden: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/nlp/MODEL_GARDEN.md
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/nlp/docs/pretrained_models.md
Or huggingface TF models if you are using Tensorflow.

Comment: BTW, here is a recent blogpost from huggingface on training RoBERTa on TPUs: https://huggingface.co/blog/tf_tpu